# Rails web application need to send Desktop Notification targeted to its registered user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, desktop

**Ruby 2.3.0**

**Rails 4.2.6**

In my web application I need to send Desktop Notifications to a target user when a particular task is assigned to him.

Use-case goes like following:

Let's assume following users are available in the system:

- System Admin (admin@example.com)
- John (john@example.com)
- Peter (peter@example.com)

Let's assume system-admin has created following tasks

Task 1) Book an appointment with Bank executive

Task 2) Book a flight to New York

Now system-admin assigns Task 2) to Peter and Task 1) to John

Now there are two scenarios:

- Users are using the web-application live i.e. they are logged-in.
- Users are offline.

**Scenario 1) - Users are using the web-application live i.e. they are logged-in.**

In this case when system-admin assigns the Task 2) to Peter, Peter should receive a Desktop Notification saying You are assigned this task probably with a link to the task. Clicking the link to the task takes Peter to the Task Details page which might contain more details about the task.

Similar should be the behaviour when Task 1) is assigned to John by system-admin.

**Scenario 2) - Users are offline**

In this case when system-admin assigns the Task 2) to Peter and Task 1) to John both of them should see the Desktop Notification when they log-in to the web-application.

I don't know how much feasible the Scenario 2) is and whether it is possible to implement it or not.

I have no idea about how to implement Desktop Notifications. This is my first attempt and hence clueless. I tried to search the web for possible solutions but I ended up on following libraries:

- [HTML5-Desktop-Notifications](https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications) - This looks like Deprecated
- [notify.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/notify.js)
- [notification.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/notification.js)

and some more article links. But all of these focused on how to create and display a Notification. But none of them was convincing enough in guiding me to implement my use-case. Hence decided to seek help from the SO community.

I also found an app [Noti](https://notiapp.com/) and which has published a Ruby gem and a [tutorial](http://api.notiapp.com/tutorials/rails) about implementing Desktop Notifications in a Rails app with Noti. Going through it seems like Noti is what can help me out in my case but Noti can work only when my web application users install Noti's native desktop application on their machine. Thus I am reluctant in pursuing it and am finding for out-of-the-box alternatives.

So can I please get the guidance from the community on my requirement I have mentioned above and what tools or libraries can help me achieve my goal.

Thanks.